# How to confront error "wrong embedding dimension" in cajolst R function?

Tags: r

When I try to use cajolst function from urca package I get a strange error.
would you please guide me how can i confront the problem?

```
   result<-urca::cajolst(data ,trend = FALSE, K = 2, season = NULL)
```

> Error in embed(diff(x), K) : wrong embedding dimension.

```
  dates     A        G
2016-11-30  0        0
2016-12-01  -3.53   3.198
2016-12-02  -2.832  8.703
2016-12-04  -2.666  7.799
2016-12-05  -0.54   7.701
2016-12-06  -1.296  4.685
2016-12-07  -1.785  -4.587
2016-12-08  -6.834  -3.696
2016-12-09  -9.624  -5.461
2016-12-11  -11.374 -0.423
2016-12-12  -6.037  -1.614
2016-12-13  -5.934  -3.231
2016-12-14  -7.279  1.072
2016-12-15  -7.859  -4.823
2016-12-16  -15.132 10.838
2016-12-19  -15.345 11.5
2016-12-20  -15.673 6.639
2016-12-21  -15.391 11.162
2016-12-22  -14.357 7.032
2016-12-23  -14.99  12.355
2016-12-26  -15.626 10.944
2016-12-27  -12.297 10.215
2016-12-28  -13.967 5.957
2016-12-29  -12.946 3.446
2016-12-30  -19.681 10.274
2017-01-02  -18.24  8.781
2017-01-03  -16.83  1.116
2017-01-04  -18.189 -0.036
2017-01-05  -15.897 -1.441
2017-01-06  -20.196 -8.534
2017-01-09  -14.57  -28.768
2017-01-10  -13.27  -29.821
2017-01-11  -8.85   -38.881
2017-01-12  -6.375  -50.885
2017-01-13  -8.056  -51.321
2017-01-16  -5.217  -63.619
2017-01-17  -4.75   -39.163
2017-01-18  3.505   -46.309
2017-01-19  10.939  -45.825
2017-01-20  9.248   -42.973
2017-01-23  9.532   -33.396
2017-01-24  4.235   -31.38
2017-01-25  -1.885  -19.21
2017-01-26  -5.027  -15.74
2017-01-27  0.015   -23.029
2017-01-30  -0.685  -30.773
2017-01-31  -2.692  -25.544
2017-02-01  -2.654  -17.912
2017-02-02  4.002   -43.309
2017-02-03  4.813   -52.627
2017-02-06  7.049   -49.965
2017-02-07  10.003  -40.568
2017-02-08  8.996   -39.828
2017-02-09  7.047   -41.19
2017-02-10  7.656   -50.853
2017-02-13  4.986   -41.318
2017-02-14  8.493   -51.946
2017-02-15  12.547  -59.538
2017-02-16  10.327  -54.496
2017-02-17  7.09    -57.571
2017-02-20  11.633  -54.91
2017-02-21  12.664  -51.597
2017-02-22  16.103  -57.819
2017-02-23  14.25   -51.336
2017-02-24  7.794   -54.898
2017-02-27  15.27   -55.754
2017-02-28  19.984  -58.37
2017-03-01  23.899  -70.73
2017-03-02  16.63   -56.29
2017-03-03  16.443  -55.858
2017-03-06  17.901  -59.377
2017-03-07  19.067  -64.383
2017-03-08  17.219  -57.829
2017-03-09  15.694  -55.022
2017-03-10  17.351  -60.431
2017-03-13  18.945  -59.79
2017-03-14  20.001  -64.848
2017-03-15  23.852  -73.806
2017-03-16  22.697  -64.191
2017-03-17  26.892  -65.328
2017-03-20  29.221  -72.764
2017-03-21  25.165  -53.427
2017-03-22  22.998  -51.676
2017-03-23  20.072  -40.57
2017-03-24  20.758  -43.654
2017-03-27  20.062  -33.672
2017-03-28  22.066  -47.184
2017-03-29  22.363  -54.57
2017-03-30  20.684  -48.199
2017-03-31  17.056  -40.887
2017-04-03  19.12   -39.618
2017-04-04  16.359  -37.1
2017-04-05  18.643  -32.734
2017-04-06  14.708  -30.455
2017-04-07  8.403   -33.553
2017-04-10  6.072   -29.048
2017-04-11  5.186   -20.696
2017-04-12  4.248   -20.924
2017-04-13  12.803  -31.075
2017-04-14  12.566  -29.768
2017-04-17  14.065  -28.906
2017-04-18  14.5    4.121
2017-04-19  13.865  8.835
2017-04-20  16.126  6.191
2017-04-21  17.591  3.77
2017-04-24  22.3    -2.497
2017-04-25  22.731  7.408
2017-04-26  19.146  18.45
2017-04-27  19.052  25.541
2017-04-28  21.889  26.878
2017-05-01  27.323  14.362
2017-05-02  29.93   17.525
2017-05-03  19.835  29.856
2017-05-04  19.683  36.72
2017-05-05  13.545  41.055
2017-05-08  14.165  43.544
2017-05-09  11.325  49.978
2017-05-10  10.143  47.072
2017-05-11  13.718  38.901
2017-05-12  14.216  36.017
2017-05-15  13.701  33.797
2017-05-16  13.505  33.867
2017-05-17  13.456  38.004
2017-05-18  12.613  37.758
2017-05-19  11.166  40.367
2017-05-22  12.221  34.022
2017-05-23  13.682  29.793
2017-05-24  10.05   26.701
2017-05-25  10.122  31.394
2017-05-26  7.592   20.073
2017-05-29  6.796   23.809
2017-05-30  9.638   16.1
2017-05-31  7.983   29.043
2017-06-01  3.594   39.557
2017-06-02  8.763   27.863
2017-06-05  12.157  22.397
2017-06-06  13.383  19.053
2017-06-07  20.52   17.449
2017-06-08  19.534  -1.615
2017-06-09  16.011  -1.989
2017-06-12  9.153   -9.294
2017-06-13  4.295   -0.897
2017-06-14  9.743   -9.818
2017-06-15  10.386  -8.255
2017-06-16  11.983  -12.522
2017-06-19  9.513   -12.931
2017-06-20  10.298  -21.024
2017-06-21  11.087  -11.801
2017-06-22  4.472   -9.048
2017-06-23  9.416   -9.592
2017-06-26  9.686   -12.006
2017-06-27  6.424   -2.632
2017-06-28  3.062   -1.016
2017-06-29  5.593   -0.825
2017-06-30  3.531   0.914
2017-07-03  3.208   -2.596
2017-07-04  -6.373  4.289
2017-07-05  -5.149  5.917
2017-07-06  -6.104  12.75
2017-07-07  -9.565  1.615
2017-07-10  -8.961  -0.053
2017-07-11  -4.065  -8.541
2017-07-12  -10.133 -11.286
2017-07-13  -6.223  -15.181
2017-07-14  -1.524  -14.396
2017-07-17  -1.613  -14.61
2017-07-18  5.781   -35.473
2017-07-19  8.243   -44.186
2017-07-20  7.665   -49.857
2017-07-21  0.485   -41.286
2017-07-24  -0.638  -39.127
2017-07-25  0.767   -40.952
2017-07-26  3.566   -44.388
2017-07-27  6.834   -42.543
2017-07-28  1.306   -37.657
2017-07-31  5.839   -34.048
2017-08-01  5.838   -28.939
2017-08-02  7.298   -26.566
2017-08-03  6.804   -32.876
2017-08-04  8.989   -38.618
2017-08-07  8.862   -36.676
2017-08-08  8.234   -40.893
2017-08-09  7.39    -35.16
2017-08-10  8.593   -35.555
2017-08-11  7.253   -35.175
2017-08-14  5.593   -33.644
2017-08-15  4.528   -37.82
2017-08-16  6.752   -53.217
2017-08-17  6.284   -49.252
2017-08-18  4.765   -55.602
2017-08-21  3.905   -54.32
2017-08-22  1.76    -57.853
2017-08-23  0.406   -58.925
2017-08-24  -2.438  -58.098
2017-08-25  -0.791  -56.682
2017-08-28  2.173   -51.278
2017-08-29  2.523   -54.353
2017-08-30  4.482   -46.325
2017-08-31  0.246   -52.567
2017-09-01  -4.214  -53.636
2017-09-04  -4.548  -52.735
2017-09-05  -1.781  -50.421
2017-09-06  -10.463 -51.122
2017-09-07  -13.119 -52.433
2017-09-08  -11.716 -43.493
2017-09-11  -16.15  -43.142
2017-09-12  -12.478 -29.335
2017-09-13  -16.457 -31.697
2017-09-14  -14.615 -15.13
2017-09-15  -13.911 3.023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issue is that the 'Date' column is also included and secondly, the `season` is not needed, it can be `FALSE` or specify an integer value

```
library(urca)
out <- cajolst(data[-1] ,trend = FALSE, K = 2, season =FALSE)
```

If there is a `season` effect and it is `quarterly, the value would be 4

```
out1 <- cajolst(data[-1] ,trend = FALSE, K = 2, season = 4)
out1
##################################################### 
# Johansen-Procedure Unit Root / Cointegration Test # 
##################################################### 

#The value of the test statistic is: 3.6212 13.2233
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(dates = c("2016-11-30", "2016-12-01", "2016-12-02", 
"2016-12-04", "2016-12-05", "2016-12-06", "2016-12-07", "2016-12-08", 
"2016-12-09", "2016-12-11", "2016-12-12", "2016-12-13", "2016-12-14", 
"2016-12-15", "2016-12-16", "2016-12-19", "2016-12-20", "2016-12-21", 
"2016-12-22", "2016-12-23", "2016-12-26", "2016-12-27", "2016-12-28", 
"2016-12-29", "2016-12-30", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", 
"2017-01-05", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-09", "2017-01-10", "2017-01-11", 
"2017-01-12", "2017-01-13", "2017-01-16", "2017-01-17", "2017-01-18", 
"2017-01-19", "2017-01-20", "2017-01-23", "2017-01-24", "2017-01-25", 
"2017-01-26", "2017-01-27", "2017-01-30", "2017-01-31", "2017-02-01", 
"2017-02-02", "2017-02-03", "2017-02-06", "2017-02-07", "2017-02-08", 
"2017-02-09", "2017-02-10", "2017-02-13", "2017-02-14", "2017-02-15", 
"2017-02-16", "2017-02-17", "2017-02-20", "2017-02-21", "2017-02-22", 
"2017-02-23", "2017-02-24", "2017-02-27", "2017-02-28", "2017-03-01", 
"2017-03-02", "2017-03-03", "2017-03-06", "2017-03-07", "2017-03-08", 
"2017-03-09", "2017-03-10", "2017-03-13", "2017-03-14", "2017-03-15", 
"2017-03-16", "2017-03-17", "2017-03-20", "2017-03-21", "2017-03-22", 
"2017-03-23", "2017-03-24", "2017-03-27", "2017-03-28", "2017-03-29", 
"2017-03-30", "2017-03-31", "2017-04-03", "2017-04-04", "2017-04-05", 
"2017-04-06", "2017-04-07", "2017-04-10", "2017-04-11", "2017-04-12", 
"2017-04-13", "2017-04-14", "2017-04-17", "2017-04-18", "2017-04-19", 
"2017-04-20", "2017-04-21", "2017-04-24", "2017-04-25", "2017-04-26", 
"2017-04-27", "2017-04-28", "2017-05-01", "2017-05-02", "2017-05-03", 
"2017-05-04", "2017-05-05", "2017-05-08", "2017-05-09", "2017-05-10", 
"2017-05-11", "2017-05-12", "2017-05-15", "2017-05-16", "2017-05-17", 
"2017-05-18", "2017-05-19", "2017-05-22", "2017-05-23", "2017-05-24", 
"2017-05-25", "2017-05-26", "2017-05-29", "2017-05-30", "2017-05-31", 
"2017-06-01", "2017-06-02", "2017-06-05", "2017-06-06", "2017-06-07", 
"2017-06-08", "2017-06-09", "2017-06-12", "2017-06-13", "2017-06-14", 
"2017-06-15", "2017-06-16", "2017-06-19", "2017-06-20", "2017-06-21", 
"2017-06-22", "2017-06-23", "2017-06-26", "2017-06-27", "2017-06-28", 
"2017-06-29", "2017-06-30", "2017-07-03", "2017-07-04", "2017-07-05", 
"2017-07-06", "2017-07-07", "2017-07-10", "2017-07-11", "2017-07-12", 
"2017-07-13", "2017-07-14", "2017-07-17", "2017-07-18", "2017-07-19", 
"2017-07-20", "2017-07-21", "2017-07-24", "2017-07-25", "2017-07-26", 
"2017-07-27", "2017-07-28", "2017-07-31", "2017-08-01", "2017-08-02", 
"2017-08-03", "2017-08-04", "2017-08-07", "2017-08-08", "2017-08-09", 
"2017-08-10", "2017-08-11", "2017-08-14", "2017-08-15", "2017-08-16", 
"2017-08-17", "2017-08-18", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-22", "2017-08-23", 
"2017-08-24", "2017-08-25", "2017-08-28", "2017-08-29", "2017-08-30", 
"2017-08-31", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-04", "2017-09-05", "2017-09-06", 
"2017-09-07", "2017-09-08", "2017-09-11", "2017-09-12", "2017-09-13", 
"2017-09-14", "2017-09-15"), A = c(0, -3.53, -2.832, -2.666, 
-0.54, -1.296, -1.785, -6.834, -9.624, -11.374, -6.037, -5.934, 
-7.279, -7.859, -15.132, -15.345, -15.673, -15.391, -14.357, 
-14.99, -15.626, -12.297, -13.967, -12.946, -19.681, -18.24, 
-16.83, -18.189, -15.897, -20.196, -14.57, -13.27, -8.85, -6.375, 
-8.056, -5.217, -4.75, 3.505, 10.939, 9.248, 9.532, 4.235, -1.885, 
-5.027, 0.015, -0.685, -2.692, -2.654, 4.002, 4.813, 7.049, 10.003, 
8.996, 7.047, 7.656, 4.986, 8.493, 12.547, 10.327, 7.09, 11.633, 
12.664, 16.103, 14.25, 7.794, 15.27, 19.984, 23.899, 16.63, 16.443, 
17.901, 19.067, 17.219, 15.694, 17.351, 18.945, 20.001, 23.852, 
22.697, 26.892, 29.221, 25.165, 22.998, 20.072, 20.758, 20.062, 
22.066, 22.363, 20.684, 17.056, 19.12, 16.359, 18.643, 14.708, 
8.403, 6.072, 5.186, 4.248, 12.803, 12.566, 14.065, 14.5, 13.865, 
16.126, 17.591, 22.3, 22.731, 19.146, 19.052, 21.889, 27.323, 
29.93, 19.835, 19.683, 13.545, 14.165, 11.325, 10.143, 13.718, 
14.216, 13.701, 13.505, 13.456, 12.613, 11.166, 12.221, 13.682, 
10.05, 10.122, 7.592, 6.796, 9.638, 7.983, 3.594, 8.763, 12.157, 
13.383, 20.52, 19.534, 16.011, 9.153, 4.295, 9.743, 10.386, 11.983, 
9.513, 10.298, 11.087, 4.472, 9.416, 9.686, 6.424, 3.062, 5.593, 
3.531, 3.208, -6.373, -5.149, -6.104, -9.565, -8.961, -4.065, 
-10.133, -6.223, -1.524, -1.613, 5.781, 8.243, 7.665, 0.485, 
-0.638, 0.767, 3.566, 6.834, 1.306, 5.839, 5.838, 7.298, 6.804, 
8.989, 8.862, 8.234, 7.39, 8.593, 7.253, 5.593, 4.528, 6.752, 
6.284, 4.765, 3.905, 1.76, 0.406, -2.438, -0.791, 2.173, 2.523, 
4.482, 0.246, -4.214, -4.548, -1.781, -10.463, -13.119, -11.716, 
-16.15, -12.478, -16.457, -14.615, -13.911), G = c(0, 3.198, 
8.703, 7.799, 7.701, 4.685, -4.587, -3.696, -5.461, -0.423, -1.614, 
-3.231, 1.072, -4.823, 10.838, 11.5, 6.639, 11.162, 7.032, 12.355, 
10.944, 10.215, 5.957, 3.446, 10.274, 8.781, 1.116, -0.036, -1.441, 
-8.534, -28.768, -29.821, -38.881, -50.885, -51.321, -63.619, 
-39.163, -46.309, -45.825, -42.973, -33.396, -31.38, -19.21, 
-15.74, -23.029, -30.773, -25.544, -17.912, -43.309, -52.627, 
-49.965, -40.568, -39.828, -41.19, -50.853, -41.318, -51.946, 
-59.538, -54.496, -57.571, -54.91, -51.597, -57.819, -51.336, 
-54.898, -55.754, -58.37, -70.73, -56.29, -55.858, -59.377, -64.383, 
-57.829, -55.022, -60.431, -59.79, -64.848, -73.806, -64.191, 
-65.328, -72.764, -53.427, -51.676, -40.57, -43.654, -33.672, 
-47.184, -54.57, -48.199, -40.887, -39.618, -37.1, -32.734, -30.455, 
-33.553, -29.048, -20.696, -20.924, -31.075, -29.768, -28.906, 
4.121, 8.835, 6.191, 3.77, -2.497, 7.408, 18.45, 25.541, 26.878, 
14.362, 17.525, 29.856, 36.72, 41.055, 43.544, 49.978, 47.072, 
38.901, 36.017, 33.797, 33.867, 38.004, 37.758, 40.367, 34.022, 
29.793, 26.701, 31.394, 20.073, 23.809, 16.1, 29.043, 39.557, 
27.863, 22.397, 19.053, 17.449, -1.615, -1.989, -9.294, -0.897, 
-9.818, -8.255, -12.522, -12.931, -21.024, -11.801, -9.048, -9.592, 
-12.006, -2.632, -1.016, -0.825, 0.914, -2.596, 4.289, 5.917, 
12.75, 1.615, -0.053, -8.541, -11.286, -15.181, -14.396, -14.61, 
-35.473, -44.186, -49.857, -41.286, -39.127, -40.952, -44.388, 
-42.543, -37.657, -34.048, -28.939, -26.566, -32.876, -38.618, 
-36.676, -40.893, -35.16, -35.555, -35.175, -33.644, -37.82, 
-53.217, -49.252, -55.602, -54.32, -57.853, -58.925, -58.098, 
-56.682, -51.278, -54.353, -46.325, -52.567, -53.636, -52.735, 
-50.421, -51.122, -52.433, -43.493, -43.142, -29.335, -31.697, 
-15.13, 3.023)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -210L
))
```